# How to update a specific dictonary value inside a list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list like as below:

```
list1 = [{'value1': 4, 'value2': False, 'value3': (5, 4)}, {'value1': 6, 'value2': False, 'value3': (5, 0)},
            {'value1': 5, 'value2': False, 'value3': (5, 2)}, {'value1': 4, 'value2': False, 'value3': (5, 4)},
            {'value1': 3, 'value2': False, 'value3': (5, 6)}, {'value1': 2, 'value2': False, 'value3': (5, 8)},
            {'value1': 1, 'value2': True, 'value3': (5, 10)}]
```

in this list I copied the `{'value1': 4, 'value2': False, 'value3': (5, 4)}` from the list  using  `list1.insert(0, get_value_to_duplicate)`  and
inserted into the first place.
now if I try to update any value in first position(dict) it updates the 4th position values as well.

```
ele_to_copy=4
#copied 4th value which needs to be append in the beginning
get_value_to_duplicate = (next(item for item in lis1 if item["value1"] == ele_to_copy))
```

#Now update the first value:

```
list1[0]['value3'] = (0, 0)
```

This makes the list as :

```
list1 = [{'value1': 4, 'value2': False, 'value3': (0, 0)}, {'value1': 6, 'value2': False, 'value3': (5, 0)},
            {'value1': 5, 'value2': False, 'value3': (5, 2)}, {'value1': 4, 'value2': False, 'value3': (0, 0)},
            {'value1': 3, 'value2': False, 'value3': (5, 6)}, {'value1': 2, 'value2': False, 'value3': (5, 8)},
            {'value1': 1, 'value2': True, 'value3': (5, 10)}]
```

so how can I make the changes only in first element of this list instead of updating the older element from where it was copied.

Could somebody help

Comment: Almost certainly because you put the same object twice in your list. How, **exactly** did you do: "I copied the {'value1': 4, 'value2': False, 'value3': (5, 4)} from the list and inserted into the first place."?

Comment: list1.insert(0, get_value_to_duplicate) This is how I have inserted the value

Comment: you should look into the `copy` module, specifically `copy.deepcopy`

Comment: You mean to say after inserting the element I should do deep copy to the list and update the new list ?

Comment: I did the deepcopy as:

new_list = copy.deepcopy(list1)

after the I updated the value but it did not help

Comment: I am in Need of urgent can somebody help on this ?